# How to register name and log in my solana token on devnet

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, solana, nft

Everyone.
I have minted my token on solana devnet.
But I don't know to change the token name and log.
I need help in this problem.
[image]

Comment: Your problem is very important for me. Thanks. Write code behind paragraph. I will find your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, the solana explorer pulls all the token images, names, and descriptions from the [token-list](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list) repo.

You'll have to submit a PR with your token's details to get it updated on the explorer and a variety of wallets.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [token-list](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list) repo has been archived, here is the latest method to set token info on devnet:

1. Navigate to https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/
2. Upload metadata
3. Update metadata

Then you will see your token name appear on solscan, for [example](https://solscan.io/token/3sjMSbJyvPc7BVJcNwjhx82sUtFFKm5E6NXnuZLb7GVr?cluster=devnet): [image]

Comment: The correct answer must be this because the repo is already not in use